# Найти максимальный элемент на странице jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется такой динамический код html. data-id постоянно меняется. Нужно найти максимальное число data-id. В данном коде это 12.

```html
<div class="mes-cont" id="chat-window">
  <div class="frt " id="pm1" data-id="1">
    <p>ytut</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm9" data-id="9">
    <p>ytut</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm10" data-id="10">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div id="new_id"></div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm11" data-id="11">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm12" data-id="12">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так :

```js
var max = 0 , id;
$(".frt").each(function(){
   id = $(this).data('id'); 
   max = (max < id) ?id:max; 
})

console.log(max)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mes-cont" id="chat-window">
  <div class="frt " id="pm1" data-id="1">
    <p>ytut</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm9" data-id="9">
    <p>ytut</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm12" data-id="25">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm10" data-id="10">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div id="new_id"></div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm11" data-id="11">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm12" data-id="12">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вариант:

```
var id = Math.max.apply(null, $(".frt").map(function(i, el) {
  return parseInt($(el).attr("data-id"));
}).get())
```

```js
var id = Math.max.apply(null, $(".frt").map(function(i, el) {
  return parseInt($(el).attr("data-id"));
}).get())

console.log(id)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mes-cont" id="chat-window">
  <div class="frt " id="pm1" data-id="1">
    <p>ytut</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm9" data-id="9">
    <p>ytut</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm12" data-id="25">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm10" data-id="10">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div id="new_id"></div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm11" data-id="11">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
  <div class="frt " id="pm12" data-id="12">
    <p>kjjj</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает...